# updating a field of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

im currently using a combination of react redux to handle my logic for notifications. The behavior i want to execute is whenever a person clicks onto one of the object in the list , i will grab that id , send it over to my backend , and change the field , `is_read = True` . However , instead of recalling the api to grab all my notifications again just to show that , that object has been read , i wish to locate down that object from within the array and change its field `is_read=True` once my operation returns a success.

Heres some of my code :

## The Data schema

```
notifications: [{
                 id(pin):1,
                 title(pin):"no title available...",
                 datetime(pin):"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read = false,
                },
                 {
                 id(pin):2,
                 title(pin):"no title available...",
                 datetime(pin):"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read = false,
                },

],
```

## Saga:

```
//I have 2 functions here , one is to handle 1 click , the 2nd is to handle a 'clear all' button

export function* workerReadNotification(action) {
yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER_COMPONENT', loading: 'notifications' })
const data = yield call(() => axiosInstance.get(`/notifications/${notification_id}`))
yield put({ type: "UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DATA", payload: data.data })
yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER_COMPONENT', loading: 'notifications' })
if (action.message) {
    yield put({ type: "CREATE_MESSAGE", message: action.message })
}
}

export function* workerReadAllNotification(action) {
    yield put({ type: 'SHOW_LOADER_COMPONENT', loading: 'notifications' })
    const data = yield call(() => axiosInstance.post(`/notifications/readall/`,action.data))
    yield put({ type: "UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DATA", payload: data.data })
    yield put({ type: 'HIDE_LOADER_COMPONENT', loading: 'notifications' })
    if (action.message) {
        yield put({ type: "CREATE_MESSAGE", message: action.message })
    }
}
```

## Reducer:

```
const updateNotificationData = (state, action) => {
return updateObject(state, {
    //logic here to replace the fields
    });
}
```

My question is , is what is the best way to do these 2 updating operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below utility method by passing the id of object that needs to be updated.

```js
let notifications = [{
                 "id(pin)":1,
                 "title(pin)":"no title available...",
                 "datetime(pin)":"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read: false,
                },
                 {
                 "id(pin)":2,
                 "title(pin)":"no title available...",
                 "datetime(pin)":"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read: false,
                },

];

const updateObject = (data, id) => {
  return data.map(d => {
    if(id === d["id(pin)"]) {
      return {
        ...d,
        is_read: true
      }
    } else return {...d}
  })
}

console.log(updateObject(notifications, 1))
```

If you want to update more than one objects at a time then below method can be used

```js
let notifications = [{
                 "id(pin)":1,
                 "title(pin)":"no title available...",
                 "datetime(pin)":"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read: false,
                },
                 {
                 "id(pin)":2,
                 "title(pin)":"no title available...",
                 "datetime(pin)":"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read: false,
                },
                 {
                 "id(pin)":3,
                 "title(pin)":"no title available...",
                 "datetime(pin)":"2020-06-12T10:33:27.173774Z",
                 is_read: false,
                }

];

const updateObjectByIds = (data, idArray) => {
  return data.map(d => {
    if(idArray.includes(d["id(pin)"])) {
      return {
        ...d,
        is_read: true
      }
    } else return {...d}
  })
}

console.log(updateObjectByIds(notifications, [1, 2]))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much , i have tried using the code and it works perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :-)